# Redshift STL_LOAD_ERRORS - History

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I think `STL_LOAD_ERRORS` gets cleaned/truncated automatically.
Is there a way to get the errors which were occurred previously.
Basically I want to get the details from `STL_LOAD_ERRORS`for the errors which were occurred earlier and currently are cleaned up from the table.
Is there way to get it ?

Comment: I have not tried it and do not know if it works but you use table restore feature from older snapshot , read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html#working-with-snapshot-restore-table-from-snapshot

Comment: Check this space https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_intro_STL_tables.html it says that "To manage disk space, the STL log tables only retain approximately two to five days of log history, depending on log usage and available disk space. If you want to retain the log data, you will need to periodically copy it to other tables or unload it to Amazon S3." Check if you can get hold of log files on the disk.

Comment: @KushVyas : Unfortunately , I don't have snapshot for that date, but technically this solution can work. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @NavjotBhardwaj : How can I access the underlying Redshift Disk ?

Comment: Not sure about that but you can enable audit logs and then logs will be available on S3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/db-auditing.html